# Django Model Query to Group Results By Month/Year and Display Each Month's Results in Separate DIV Elements

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to create a model (name is Event) query in my view that groups events by month/year (launch_date field), then I want to display (using a for loop) the group of each month's events in it's own DIV element. For example, all September 2019 events would be in a single DIV element, all October 2019 events would be in a single DIV element next to September, and so on.

The model is really simple:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    overview = models.TextField(max_length=1200,blank=True)
    launch_date = models.DateField(blank=True, default=datetime.now)
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

Comment: @Cooper, that worked perfectly! Thank you! I continue to forget about the rich library of Django template tags as I encounter these types of issues. I will spend more time digging into the library for sure.

Comment: great, glad to help